# css-grid: not fitting to max-content (when overflowing)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm in the process of rendering tables that are defined by an XBRL Taxonomy. I've chosen to use css-grid because some structures are deeply nested tables. An example can be found here: [Blancesheet](https://taxonomie-viewer.logius.nl/#/dts/kvk-rpt-jaarverantwoording-2021-nlgaap-micro.xsd/linkroles/linkroles/kvk-lr_BalanceSheetMicroEntities)
Most of the time css-grid behaves exactly as intended, things go awry when the content starts to overflow on the x-axis. [Movement schedule](https://taxonomie-viewer.logius.nl/#/dts/kvk-rpt-jaarverantwoording-2021-nlgaap-middelgroot-publicatiestukken.xsd/linkroles/linkroles/kvk-lr_NotesProvisionsMovement). Instead of max-content the browser decides that min-width is what is used.
[image: Overlapping labels]

The table-grid is defined as followed:

```
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(x, minmax(100px, max-content)); 
  grid-template-rows: repeat(y, minmax(30px, max-content));
```

where x and y are of course the number of columns and rows in the table. Is there any way to tell the browser to adhere *max-content* instead of falling back to 100px?

A second problem, which is a result of the chosen method. The table [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCYw9.png) has a nested label-structure on the third row. This is accomplished by using a 2 columns wide div, where the children are 1 column wide. But the outer label is long and will take two lines. As a result the first child-label will overlap. Any thoughts how to address this and make the outer div take more space?

[image: overlapping because of height issue]

Any suggestion is welcome, I tried a lot, but so far out of luck